# moving one activity to another where titles fetched from api in searchview

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Actually the problem is ,in searchview my suggestions are showing properly which is fetched from api so here is the ss of search activity :

when click on gridview of suggestion it takes me to list view activity

I got it this is because I have used getadadpterposition() in adapter

see this-->

```
                intent.putExtra("idSLnext", movieList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
```

`
suggestionAdapter:

```
public class SuggestionAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<SuggestionAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable
   {

private Context context;
private List<StartLearning.SlModel> movieList;
private List<StartLearning.SlModel> movieListAgain;

public SuggestionAdapter(Context context, List<StartLearning.SlModel> movieList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.movieList = movieList;
    this.movieListAgain=movieList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SuggestionAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_chips,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SuggestionAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tvSuggestion.setText(movieListAgain.get(position).getTitle());
  /*  holder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            movieListAgain.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(movieList != null){
        return movieListAgain.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView tvSuggestion;
    ImageView ivDelete;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvSuggestion=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSuggestion);
      //  ivDelete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextSLactivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("title", movieList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("idSLnext", movieList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                //Log.e("ashwini",WAmdel.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final List<StartLearning.SlModel> results = new ArrayList<StartLearning.SlModel>();
            if (movieList == null)
                movieListAgain = movieList;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (movieListAgain != null & movieListAgain.size() > 0) {
                    for (final StartLearning.SlModel g : movieListAgain) {
                        if (g.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().trim()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            movieListAgain = (ArrayList<StartLearning.SlModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}

public void setMovieList(Context context, final List<StartLearning.SlModel> movieList){
    this.context = context;
    if(this.movieList == null){
        this.movieList = movieList;
        this.movieListAgain = movieList;
        notifyItemChanged(0, movieListAgain.size());
    } else {
        final DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtil.Callback() {
            @Override
            public int getOldListSize() {
                return SuggestionAdapter.this.movieList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getNewListSize() {
                // return movieList.size();
                return (movieList == null) ? 0 : movieList.size();

            }

            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return SuggestionAdapter.this.movieList.get(oldItemPosition).getTitle() == movieList.get(newItemPosition).getTitle();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {

                StartLearning.SlModel newMovie = SuggestionAdapter.this.movieList.get(oldItemPosition);

                StartLearning.SlModel oldMovie = movieList.get(newItemPosition);

                return newMovie.getTitle() == oldMovie.getTitle() ;
            }
        });
        this.movieList = movieList;
        this.movieListAgain = movieList;
        result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }
}
```

}

search activity :

```
public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {

SearchView searchView;
RecyclerView recyclerView,recyclerViewSuggestions;
TextView tvSuggestions;
SuggestionAdapter suggestionAdapter;
SuggestionAdapter1 suggestionAdapter1;
List<StartLearning.SlModel> movieList;
List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel> modelList1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);
    Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    searchView=findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    tvSuggestions=findViewById(R.id.tvSuggestions);
    recyclerViewSuggestions=findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewSuggestions);
    recyclerViewSuggestions.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
    searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
    searchView.setIconified(true);

    SLApiSevice service = SLApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(SLApiSevice.class);
    retrofit2.Call<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> call = service.getMySlmodel();

   call.enqueue(new Callback<List<StartLearning.SlModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> call, Response<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> response) {

            movieList = response.body();
            if(movieList.size()!=0){
                tvSuggestions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                suggestionAdapter=new SuggestionAdapter(Search.this,movieList);
                recyclerViewSuggestions.setAdapter(suggestionAdapter);
                Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: size of movielist "+movieList);
                suggestionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                suggestionAdapter.setMovieList(Search.this,movieList);

            }
            else{
                tvSuggestions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvSuggestions.setText("No Suggestions Found");
            }





       }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG","Response = "+t.toString());


        }
    });
    GetAheadApiService service1 = GetAheadApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetAheadApiService.class);
    retrofit2.Call<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>> call1 = service1.getaheadapi();
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>> call, Response<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>> response) {

            modelList1 = response.body();
            if(modelList1.size()!=0){
                tvSuggestions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                suggestionAdapter1=new SuggestionAdapter1(Search.this,modelList1);
                recyclerViewSuggestions.setAdapter(suggestionAdapter1);
                Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: size of movielist "+movieList);
               // suggestionAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                suggestionAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                suggestionAdapter1.setMovieList(Search.this,modelList1);

            }
            else{
                tvSuggestions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvSuggestions.setText("No Suggestions Found");
            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG","Response = "+t.toString());


        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String query) {
            SLApiSevice service = SLApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(SLApiSevice.class);
            retrofit2.Call<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> call = service.getMySlmodel();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<StartLearning.SlModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> call, Response<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> response) {

                    movieList = response.body();
                    if(movieList.size()!=0){
                        tvSuggestions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        suggestionAdapter=new SuggestionAdapter(Search.this,movieList);
                        recyclerViewSuggestions.setAdapter(suggestionAdapter);
                        Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: size of movielist "+movieList);
                        suggestionAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                        suggestionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        suggestionAdapter.setMovieList(Search.this,movieList);

                    }
                    else{
                        tvSuggestions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tvSuggestions.setText("No Suggestions Found");
                    }



                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<List<StartLearning.SlModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("TAG","Response = "+t.toString());


                }
            });
            GetAheadApiService service1 = GetAheadApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetAheadApiService.class);
            retrofit2.Call<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>> call1 = service1.getaheadapi();
            call1.enqueue(new Callback<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>> call, Response<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>> response) {

                    modelList1 = response.body();
                    if(modelList1.size()!=0){
                        tvSuggestions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        suggestionAdapter1=new SuggestionAdapter1(Search.this,modelList1);
                        recyclerViewSuggestions.setAdapter(suggestionAdapter1);
                        Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: size of movielist "+movieList);
                        suggestionAdapter1.getFilter().filter(query);
                        suggestionAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        suggestionAdapter1.setMovieList(Search.this,modelList1);

                    }
                    else{
                        tvSuggestions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tvSuggestions.setText("No Suggestions Found");
                    }



                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<List<GetAhead.GetaheadModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("TAG","Response = "+t.toString());


                }
            });

            return false;
        }

    });


}





@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() ==android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}}
```

next activity to get intent :

```
public class NextSLactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private NextSLJavaAdapter adapter;
private NextSLModel DescriptList;

private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
private Fragment fragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
Button button1;
Button button2;
Button button3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nextslearning);
    button1=findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3=findViewById(R.id.button3);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id. toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("idSLnext");
    Log.e("ashwini", String.valueOf(id));
    setFragment(new JavaFragment());
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.javabutton);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    setFragment(new JavaFragment());
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.javabutton);
    button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demobutton);
    button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demobutton);

}
     });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setFragment(new XMLFragmet());
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.javabutton);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demobutton);
            button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demobutton);


        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setFragment(new DemoFragment());
           button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.javabutton);
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demobutton);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demobutton);


        }
    });



}

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=   fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,fragment);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        @Override
         public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
         if (item.getItemId() ==android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add your adapter implementation?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman added